# Debugging Android Apps on Dell Venue 7 using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently bought Dell Venue 7 tablet. I am planning to use that for testing and debugging android apps. Unfortunately the usb driver for that device does not exits. I checked the dell website and they say that the driver for that device is not hosted on their website. They haven't provided information regarding where i can get the drivers for that device.

I had Samsung Galaxy tab 3 and for that device i was able to download the device driver from Samsung website and test and debug applications using eclipse. Dell Venue 7 does not have device drivers.

Any help regarding how i can test and debug applications on Dell Venue 7 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just ended up calling Dell customer support after long struggle!!! The customer support rep. told me that I cannot debug my applications using USB cable the way i can do it with Samsung Galaxy Tab!! Bummer, the device is going back :(

Answer (score 18):

sonicbabbler's solution did not work out well for me. I was still not able to force windows to recognize tablet and therefore adb was blind.

I've found solution here:
http://opensource.dell.com/releases/venue8/developer-edition/Dell%20Tablet%20Install%20Instructions.pdf
in section "Install the USB driver for adb mode".

Steps that need to be taken:

1. Turn on “USB debugging” on your tablet (Settings -> System -> Developer Options)
2. Connect the Tablet to your computer
3. Open the device manager (Control Panel -> System and Security -> Device Manager)
4. Right Click on unrecognized device (in my case that was: “Other Device / Android”) -> Properties
5. Select the “Details” tab then choose “Hardware Ids” from the drop down list
6. Copy the two values from the window
7. Navigate to the location where Android SDK is installed (if you have Android Studio installed it is usually in {android_studio_dir}\sdk)
8. Edit the file sdk->extras->google->usb_driver->android_winusb.inf file (if you are missing such path - install google usb driver using Android SDK Manager)
9. Add the ID’s that you copied into the file and save the file. Make sure that you add the entries to both the 32-bit section ([Google.NTx86]) and the 64-bit section ([Google.NTamd64]) of the file
10. Back to the “Device Manager” Window, Right Click on “Android” and select “Update Driver Software”
11. Select “Browse my computer for Driver software”
12. Click the “Browse” button
13. Browse to the location of the “sdk->extras->google->usb_driver” in the SDK
14. Select “Next”, Select “Install this driver software anyway”
15. The success screen will be displayed, click “Close”

Comment: I tried many methods from a lot of Googling, this is the only one I found that worked for a Dell Venue 8. Just to be thorough, these are the exact lines that I added to the 32 & 64bit sections of the inf file: ;Dell Venue 8
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, XXX_DRIVER_ID_1_XXX
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, XXX_DRIVER_ID_2_XXX

Comment: This are the exact lines to be added in the .inf file            ;DELL Venus 7
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_413C&PID_B11B&REV_????&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_413C&PID_B11B&MI_01

Comment: @lenrok258 + SyamantakBasu answers helped for me (Dell Venue 7 3470 LTE) thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I just got a Venue 8 and was able to get this working. Here is what I did.

1. Put the Venue in developer mode - SETTINGS > ABOUT > tap the Build Number seven times.
2. Go to SETTINGS > DEVELOPER OPTIONS > and check the USB Debugging option
3. Plug it into your computer - I'm using Windows 8.1.
4. Open the Device Manager and locate the Android ? device.
5. Download the Intel Android driver, I used v1.1.5
   https://secure-software.intel.com/es-es/protected-download/385047/494732
6. The install will fail on Win8.1, extract the EXE with 7zip
7. In the device manager right click on Android-Phone > Browse my computer for driver software > Choose Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer > Select Android device > Have Disk > Navigate to the folder you unpacked the exe and select "android_winusb.inf" > Select Android Bootloader Interface > Press OK on the warning to proceed
8. In the device manager it will show up at "Android Phone/Android Bootloader Interface"
9. Open Eclipse and browse to the Android Device Chooser and under Choose a running Android device, the option Dell-venue_8_3830-DellVenue8... should show up.
10. I was able to successfully deploy an app to the device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up getting Google Nexus 7. Initially i ran into similar issues, where i could not put the device into debug mode. After search on SO, i found a post that mentioned something about tapping the model number of the device 7 times to enable debug mode on that device!!! What a hack, why would device maker make this process so cumbersome!!! Anyhow i finally got the Nexus 7 working. Thanks for the post.

Comment: This helped me, too, with a Dell Venue 8, after trying and failing to get help through Dell's support channels. English link is https://secure-software.intel.com/en-us/protected-download/385047/494732 and I had three choices for drivers, picked the Google "Android ADB Interface" which worked.

Answer (score 3):

I did this before, while having the same issue on my Windows 8.1 Computer:

1. Right click on the EXE, select "Properties".
2. Select the tab "Compatibility".
3. Enable the check box "Execute this program in compatibility mode for" and select "Windows 7" and click "Accept".

It should be working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Dell Venue 7 with Android 4.4.4.
To allow Eclipse Adt debuggin I followed about tips, and get the MTP driver's hardware id at Windows' Device Manager. 
It is slightly different from ID above. perhaps because I'm using a newer/updated Venue 7. 
On "About Tablet", I have the following:
Software Version: Venue7 3740_V2.10_141224-NoModem
Version Number: YTP802A142000

So I added the following lines to my android_winusb.inf file at folder C:\Android\ADT\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver, in both sections [Google.NTx86] and [Google.NTamd64]

```
;Dell Venue 7 3740 - Android 4.4.4  - software version Venue7 3740_V2.10_141224-NoModem
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_413C&PID_B133&REV_????&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_413C&PID_B133&MI_01
```

I got those values from Device Manager, as stated on steps 3 to 5 from leram258 post. 
 After the update, I went back to Device Manager and forced the unrecognised device  MTP to updated drivers, just as described at step 10 and forward, from lerom258 post.

Works just fine.