# Adb interface drivers needed?

Tags: android

I am trying to add my Dell Venue 7 Tablet with Android to my PC for developing and I connected it and my Computer management tab, I got the following
Other Devices
ADB Interface( with question mark)
I tried to fix this problem updating Driver Software from Android SDK/ but, this one was not find. I went to the Dell drivers and I could not find it either.
I read that the Clockworkmod drivers Version 7.0.0.4 date 8/27/2012 would work well with my mobile device.
For it, Could anybody help me to find the correct drivers for this tablet?
Thanks in advance
Alejandro Castan

Answer (score 0):

Here placed a similar question: [Debugging Android Apps on Dell Venue 7 using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751643/debugging-android-apps-on-dell-venue-7-using-eclipse)

And it looks like first comment contain instructions to make it work. I never faced such kind of a problem, so I cant say if that instuction really help, but I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Hi Kens, thanks for your help. I tried the solution in this topic and it is not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should install the adb driver from http://adbdriver.com/downloads/.

My android mobile phone works well now after installing this one.