# Dell Venue 8 not being recognized by adb?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

So I have USB Debugging enabled on the device and its plugged in via USB. Currently, executing `adb devices` lists nothing in Android Studio terminal. I've checked Device Manager and the device is successfully showing up under "Portable Devices" as "Venue 8 7840". The Dell website doesnt list any drivers for this device.

Using `Update Driver Software` in Device Manager says the device driver is up to date and lists `MTP USB Device`.

I've found threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751643/debugging-android-apps-on-dell-venue-7-using-eclipse) and even though my device is listed in the Device Manager I tried editing the `android_winusb.inf` anyway, but the issue persists.

Running Win 7, AS 1.3.

Any insight into this issue is appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution  [Dell Venue 7/8 Unlocked Bootloader](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2551863)

Comment: Indeed if it works, I managed to recognize the device, but you have not developed a good working your research

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on your device says it runs Android 4.2.2.
If this is the Android version on your Dell Venue, then you should have received a dialog on your Android device, asking whether to accept an RSA key that allows debugging through your computer. Acknowledging this dialog should then unlock the Android device and allow debugging.

Did you receive the security dialog?

If not, it also requires that you have adb version 1.0.31 (available with SDK Platform-tools r16.0.1 and higher) in order to debug on a device running Android 4.2.2 or higher.

You can run "adb version" (without the quotes) on a your terminal/command prompt to get the adb version you're running.

See Android Developer website on Enabling ADB:
[Enabling adb Debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#Enabling)

I found Android XDA has universal adb drivers for Dell Android devices.

[Dell ADB Universal Drivers](http://androidxda.com/download-dell-usb-drivers)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but this tool should help you: http://adbdriver.com/

Open it, click Install and follow the instructions. Good luck!