# Device not visible in "USB debugging mode" in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, usb-debugging

I am using DELL tablet "Venue7 3740" to test my applications.Though I enabled the developer settings my device is not visible in android studio when I try to run my app and yes I also clicked "Debug model when USB is connected"

**UPDATE**
 DELL "Venue7 and 8" has some small issues while connecting to use debugging mode.Get to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751643/debugging-android-apps-on-dell-venue-7-using-eclipse) to find solution on USB debugging.The answer was posted by lenrok258 and it works :)

Comment: Did you install drivers?

Comment: Amy, Yes I have tried with drivers but seem to have no luck took drivers from this link https://software.intel.com/en-us/protected-download/385047/494732/step2

Comment: which os are you on ?

Comment: tried installing android adb interface driver...

Comment: Changing USB connection on device from MTP to PTP (or vice-versa) might help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DELL "Venue7 and 8" has some small issues while connecting to use debugging mode.Get to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751643/debugging-android-apps-on-dell-venue-7-using-eclipse) to find solution on USB debugging.The answer was posted by lenrok258 and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

### The steps to enable usb debugging are

1. Go to Settings and tap on the build number a couple of times to enable developer options.
2. Open developer options and enable usb debugging.
3. Plug in your device to your computer and accept this authorization popup.

[image: Allow usb debugging popup]

4. Click OK and and you should be good to go.

### Continue reading if your device still don't turn up on the available debugging devices.

1. Once your device is connected to computer, you would have a notification saying, connected as media device/mass storage device.
2. Tap on it and change the connection type.
3. You should have that authorization popup now. Accept that and Voila. :)

[image: Change usb connection type to MTP]

Note: If you're on windows, you should install your device manufacturer's adb drivers. (If you can't find them, go for universal adb drivers.)

Reference: [Enabling usb debugging on android](https://youtu.be/Ucs34BkfPB0)

Answer (score 0):

Kingoroot for windows- simple solution to connect android mobiles with pc in USB debugging mode.